# Get categories and its sub categories REST APi

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

How to get subcategries for each category in REST API?

I tried to get category as:

```
https://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/categories/:categoryID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, are you sure you're using a valid category ID? Example:

`https://domain.com/rest/V1/categories/2`

Then you can get the sub categories from the response, `response.children`.

Comment: Just for future reference, with that endpoint, `response.children` returns a comma separated list of child IDs.

Comment: @PaulBlundell The painful turth that Magento like to develop the Framework to 75% of it's maximum potenial. Leave the 25% to the *Community*

Answer (score 1):

Your method is correct, but it will only return all child category ID's in comma-separated numbers. If you want to get sub-category information, then you need to write down a custom module with webapi.xml for your custom route to write a logic for this. This is not possible without doing customization in interface method.

Thanks

Rahul Anand